# Add programmatically search text box as a menu item in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uisearchbar, menuitem

I want to have a search input box like iTunes has. I have my toolbar which shows up, I have the below code which shows a custom toobaritem, it has the right description in grey and shows the text 'Fnurd..' in purple, but the text is not editable! This is driving me insane, what am I doing wrong ?

```
- (NSToolbarItem *)toolbar:(NSToolbar *)toolbar itemForItemIdentifier:(NSString *)itemIdentifier willBeInsertedIntoToolbar:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSToolbarItem *item = [[NSToolbarItem alloc] initWithItemIdentifier:itemIdentifier];

    if ( [itemIdentifier isEqualToString:@"SearchItem"] ) {

        //Land in sight !
        NSLog(@"### Setting up Search Item Menu Entry");        

        //Starter size
        NSRect cellFrame = NSMakeRect(0,0,200,25);
        //Create/allocate Control
        searchMenuControl = [[NSControl alloc] initWithFrame:cellFrame];
        //Create/allocate Cell
        searchMenuCell = [[NSTextFieldCell alloc] initTextCell:@"Fnurd.."];

        //Assign cell to control        
        [searchMenuControl setCell:searchMenuCell];

        //Do some polishing
        [searchMenuCell setBezelStyle:NSTextFieldRoundedBezel];
        [searchMenuCell setBackgroundColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
        [searchMenuCell setTextColor:[NSColor blackColor]];     
        [searchMenuCell setEnabled:YES];
        [searchMenuCell setCellAttribute:NSCellEditable to:YES];


        cellFrame = [searchMenuControl frame];

        // Configuration code for "SearchItem"
        [item setLabel:@"Search Records"];
        [item setPaletteLabel:[item label]];
        [item setView:searchMenuControl];
        [item setMinSize:cellFrame.size];
        [item setMaxSize:cellFrame.size];       
    }

    return [item autorelease];
}
```

Comment: My solution does not solve the problem, I still dont know why the field isnt editable..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting to stackoverflow is magic, you are bound to find the answer one google query later..

Cocoa basically has a search field widget that you can use..

```
- (NSToolbarItem *)toolbar:(NSToolbar *)toolbar itemForItemIdentifier:(NSString *)itemIdentifier willBeInsertedIntoToolbar:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSToolbarItem *item = [[NSToolbarItem alloc] initWithItemIdentifier:itemIdentifier];

    if ( [itemIdentifier isEqualToString:@"SearchItem"] ) {

        //Land in sight !
        NSLog(@"### Setting up Search Item Menu Entry");        

        searchField = [[NSSearchField alloc] init];
        [searchField sizeToFit];

        NSRect cellFrame = [searchField frame];

        // Configuration code for "SearchItem"
        [item setLabel:@"Search"];
        [item setPaletteLabel:[item label]];
        [item setView:searchField];
        [item setMinSize:cellFrame.size];
        [item setMaxSize:cellFrame.size];       
    }

    return [item autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your searchMenuCell to editable.

Comment: Greetings, I already call [searchMenuCell setCellAttribute:NSCellEditable to:YES]; Do I need anything else ?

Comment: Try [searchMenuCell setEditable: true]